# Wifi Scan Results is not broadcasting

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-wifi, android-broadcast

I'm trying to start a scan for available Wifi's and trigger a broadcast receiver as soon as the scan is complete.

I've started by adding permissions and declare receiver in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

...

<receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver">   
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In my `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` I initiate the scan:

```
// Get wifi points
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.startScan();
Log.i("WIFI_SCAN", "STARTED SCAN");
```

And finally my `WifiReceiver` class:

```
class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("WIFI_SCAN", "RESULTS RECEIVED");
    }

}
```

I'm not getting any errors and my first `Log` (`STARTED SCAN`) gets displayed, but I never get my `RESULTS RECEIVED` in the log.

I can't figure out why my BroadcastReceiver is not receiving anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BroadcastReceiver` must be public.

```
class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

should be

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```